# Drupal 7 - How do I hide the node id from the users when they are editing their nodes?

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Drupal 7 - I want to hide the node id from the users when they are editing their nodes. Is there any module available to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean hiding it from the url?

Comment: Yes. I want to hide it from the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pathauto module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto). According to its description:

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you to have URL aliases like */category/my-node-title* instead of */node/123*. The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which the administrator can change.

Comment: Pathauto is for generating the URLs for viewing the node. But if a user is allowed to edit the node then the URL should not contain the node id.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/339097 and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9008/cleaning-up-the-node-edit-url

Comment: Thanks. But the solution from links you provided have the IDs in the URL and I need it  hidden from the URL.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot provide any further help in this issue... if somebody else in the community could, would be nice.